# How much RAM can i put in a ASUS EeeTop 1602?

Tags: memory

I am trying to boost a ASUS EeeTop 1602.

I have a double slot  for SoDIMM PC2-5300 - DDR2 667 MHz.
Processor is a Atom N270 
Os is Kubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

I currently have one Nanya 1Go DDRII 667 MHz SoDIMM.

And I want to upgrade this setup.
What is the max per slot that i can put in ? 
2 x 1GB ?
2 x 2GB ?

Comment: Check the manufacturer's site.

Comment: Was not an easy search. Mostly because I m french and the frenchAsus site dont show the max ram but the ram in it if you buy. But after searching for the GMCH ( chipset) i finaly found  thats its 2GbMax.. But do you vote for 2 x 1 GB or 1 x 2 GB ...

Comment: @Xavierjazz, should i answer my self or delete the question .. i doudt that any one is going to pimp a eeetop in the future adding 2gbRam n SSD With an atomN270..So close or delete?

Comment: I would put the answer. If the question is not appropriate it will be closed. Also, once you've waited the proper amount of time (I forget how long) you can accept your answer, gaining reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASUS EeeTop 1602 supports maximum 2 x 1 GB DDR2 667 MHz,

For compatible memory upgrades, refer this link:

http://www.memorystock.com/memory/ASUSEeeTopPCET1602.html